# Openmp thread control in C

Tags: openmp

If I have a parallel section code, is it possible to assign a specific thread to each section, i.e. something of the sort

```
#pragma omp sections num_threads(2)
{
   #pragma omp section  //<---assigned to master thread
    {
      //do something
     }
    #pragma omp section  //<---assigned to the other thread
    {
      //do something
     }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assignment of OpenMP sections to threads is done in an implementation-dependent manner. The only directive that results in specific execution thread is `master`.

If you really need to give thread-specific work to each thread, use conditionals over the return value of `omp_get_thread_num()`:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2)
{
   switch (omp_get_thread_num())
   {
      case 0:
         // Code for thread 0
         break;
      case 1:
         // Code for thread 1
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Does `num_threads(2)` guarantee that you will get thread 0 and 1, not thread 2 and 3?

Comment: Threads in OpenMP parallel regions are always numbered starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

For assigning to the master thread you can use

```
#pragma omp master
```